# The rush of endorphins when doing something strictly human: writing poetry, doing scientific research. Who controls it? God or our animal instincts?

Tags: existence-of-god, pain-and-pleasure

Feelings of pleasure or pain are the main drivers in our life. If you can control the endorphins at the critical junction in an important brain, you can change the purpose of personal life as well as change the direction of history.

Of course, we can trace most of our daily pleasures or anxieties generated by brain hormone activity to similar processes that most animals have. But there are exceptions that are harder to attribute to our common animal instincts. Sometimes we have strong and irrational feelings that could be described as a sense of purpose in life. Is it coming from God?

Comment: Your balancing act from endorphins, via the purpose of the personal life to the purpose of humanity and ending with a question about God seems to me rather bold. Possibly a better approach is to restrict your question to only one of the levels. And on the specific level providing more clarity what your point is.

Comment: Wait... God exists? I missed the memo. "*I can do strong and irrational feelings all by myself.*"

Comment: @JoWehler - Thank you for letting this question stay. Sometimes the question itself is important, even though it does not have a good answer.

Comment: The recipe for a happy life is to find your true purpose. Then you get less pain and more endorphins. For some people it takes a lot of pain and persuasion.